# Abrir outra instância do Excel enquanto o VBA é executado

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

Criei uma aplicação no Excel que extrai informações da internet, diretamente para ele através do Selenium IDE Webdriver. Porém, enquanto essa aplicação roda, não consigo abrir uma nova planilha, ou uma nova instância dessa macro, existe a possibilidade de abrir uma outra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível abrir outra instância. Use o Executar do Windows (tecla Win + R) e digite `Excel -x`.